# IndexReader.getFieldNames Lucene 4

Tags: java, lucene

We're upgrading from Lucene 3.3.0 to Lucene 4.2.1 over here, and I can't seem to find the replacement for the old IndexReader.getFieldNames method.  Googling brings up [this ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-3679) which speaks of a new IndexReader.getFieldInfos method, but that was experimental and seems to be around no longer - the trail is cold.

How can I replicate the behavior of IndexReader.getFieldNames in Lucene 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the [FieldInfos](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_2_1/core/org/apache/lucene/index/FieldInfos.html) with [AtomicReader.getFieldInfos()](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_2_1/core/org/apache/lucene/index/AtomicReader.html).
Something along the lines of:

```
for (FieldInfo info : atomicReader.getFieldInfos().iterator()) {
    String name = info.name;
    //Whatever you need to do with the name.
}
```

Take a look at the [Migration Guide](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0-BETA/MIGRATE.html) for more info, there's a section about IndexReader -> AtomicReader.  If you aren't acquainted with that change yet, you'll likely find it useful information.